# 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message Unknown "form_start" function

Tags: php, forms, twig, symfony-forms, symfony

Is it possible to make a *standalone* form with symfony3 and twig? I can't get past this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unknown "form_start" function in "new.html.twig" at line 1

The [3.1 documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html) cites [this example](https://github.com/webmozart/standalone-forms), which works fine, but it's actually using 2.7

[image: screenshot of example]

My simple project is organized like this:

```
.
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── src
│   └── form.php
├── vendor
│   └── ...
└── views
    └── new.html.twig
```

## `form.php`

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRenderer;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRendererEngine;

// the Twig file that holds all the default markup for rendering forms
// this file comes with TwigBridge
$defaultFormTheme = 'form_div_layout.html.twig';

$vendorDir = realpath(__DIR__.'/../vendor');
// the path to TwigBridge library so Twig can locate the
// form_div_layout.html.twig file
$appVariableReflection = new \ReflectionClass('\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable');
$vendorTwigBridgeDir = dirname($appVariableReflection->getFileName());
// the path to your other templates
$viewsDir = realpath(__DIR__.'/../views');

$twig = new Twig_Environment(new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array(
    $viewsDir,
    $vendorTwigBridgeDir.'/Resources/views/Form',
)));
$formEngine = new TwigRendererEngine(array($defaultFormTheme));
$formEngine->setEnvironment($twig);

// create your form factory as normal
$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
    ->getFormFactory();

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;

$form = $formFactory->createBuilder()
    ->add('task', TextType::class)
    ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
    ->getForm();

var_dump($twig->render('new.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
)));
```

## `new.html.twig`

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

## `composer.json`

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/form": "^3.1",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "^3.1",
        "twig/twig": "^1.24"
    }
}
```

---

## Full Error Stack Trace

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unknown "form_start" function in "new.html.twig" at line 1.' in /var/www/a/forms/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php:574
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/a/forms/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(351): Twig_ExpressionParser-&gt;getFunctionNodeClass('form_start', 1)
#1 /var/www/a/forms/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(144): Twig_ExpressionParser-&gt;getFunctionNode('form_start', 1)
#2 /var/www/a/forms/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(84): Twig_ExpressionParser-&gt;parsePrimaryExpression()
#3 /var/www/a/forms/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(41): Twig_ExpressionParser-&gt;getPrimary()
#4 /var/www/a/forms/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Parser.php(144): Twig_ExpressionParser-&gt;parseExpression()
#5 /var/www/a/forms/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Parser.php(100): Twig_Parser-&gt;subparse(NULL, false)
#6 /var/www/a/forms/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(619): Twig_Parser-&gt;parse(Object(Twig_TokenStream))
#7 /var/www/a/forms/ in /var/www/a/forms/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php</b> on line 574
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried, [as per the exemple you provided](https://github.com/webmozart/standalone-forms/blob/2.7%2Btwig/src/setup.php#L42), to add the extension `FormExtension` to `Twig_Environment`?

Add the following snippet right after you've initialized `$twig` and `$formEngine` variables:

```
$twig->addExtension(
    new FormExtension(new TwigRenderer($formEngine))
);
```

You'll then get an error about `trans()` being unknown. Correct this by adding `symfony/translation` package : `$ composer require symfony/translation`.

Then let Twig know about this new extension in the same way as above:

```
$twig->addExtension(
    new TranslationExtension(new Translator('en'))
);
```

Don't forget the uses:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\TranslationExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
```

Comment: hmm thanks, that could be helpful, but it actually throws a new error: `'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unknown "trans" filter in "form_div_layout.html.twig"`

Comment: Yep, I guess that means the problem with `form_start()` being unknown is solved. But another rose indeed.

Comment: I'm not sure this *fixes* it because it introduces a new error before `form_start()` so it dies before it can get to that error.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll dig into that.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII: I fixed your error. See my updated answer.