# Unknown "form_start" function

Tags: php, symfony

**Contents of question**
I'm currently working on raising the symfony version of an existing web app that was created.
When I displayed the app in the browser, I got an error. I would like to know how to solve it.
Probably, it seems that the routing to the definition destination of articleAnalyticsSearch is not good.
The corresponding code has not been changed when raising symfony.

**Error message**

```
Unknown "form_start" function.
```

**Source code**

```
{% macro articleAnalyticsSearch(searchForm) %}
        {{ form_start(searchForm) }}
        {% set params = app.request.query.all|merge({'page': null}) %}
        {% set q = app.request.query.get("q")|default({}) %}
            <table>
```

```
//composer.json
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
        "classmap": [ "vendor/lsolesen/pel/src" , "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "https://pear.php.net"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "3.0.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "5.0.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.6.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.7.*",
        "lsolesen/pel": "dev-master",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.3.*",
        "shark/simple_html_dom": "dev-master",
        "pear-pear/mail_mimedecode": "1.5.*",
        "rakuten-ws/rws-php-sdk": "1.*",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "2.1.0",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.2",
        "symfony/intl": "3.0.*",
        "symfony/console": "3.0.*",
        "jms/aop-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "3.0.*",
        "symfony/form": "^3.0",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "^3.0",
        "symfony/translation": "v3.0.9"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
          "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
     ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
       ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "secure-http": false,
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.6.4"
      }
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.0-dev"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    }
}
```

**Version**
CentOS 6.7
composer 1.10
symfony 3.0.9
PHP 5.6.40

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I compared the source code with the pre-update code to see if there were any unintended changes. I also compared the current vendor with the vendor before the update and found that there were no unintended changes that seemed to be relevant.

Comment: And which package versions were changed?

Comment: Could this be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163866/twig-error-syntax-with-message-unknown-form-start-function?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried to update the packages related to twig, but it didn't change. Also, it worked with symfony 2.8 without translation, so I don't think it's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed like I was getting an error because I wasn't passing $ request to the event listener. When I resolved it, the error disappeared.